# Restore SwipeToDismiss LazyColumn Item to it's original state?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am able to do `SwipeToDismiss` but I want to restore the swiped `LazyColumn` item back to its original state.
I don't want to remove swiped item but want to restore it to its original state.

I am able to achieve this easily in `RecyclerView` by just calling `notifyItemChanged()` but can't figure out how to do this in `LazyColumn`.

Below is my code:

```
val dataList = remember{ mutableStateListOf<ListItem>()}
for(i in 0..100){
    dataList.add(ListItem("$i", "'$i' is the item number."))
}

LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    items(dataList, key = {it.id}){ item ->
        val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
            confirmStateChange = {
                if(it == DismissedToEnd || it == DismissedToStart){
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        //dataList.remove(item)
                    }, 1000)
                }
                true
            }
        ) 
        SwipeToDismiss(
            state = dismissState,
            directions = setOf(StartToEnd, EndToStart),
            dismissThresholds = { direction ->
                FractionalThreshold(if (direction == StartToEnd || direction == EndToStart) 0.25f else 0.5f)
            },
            background = {
                val direction = dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                val color by animateColorAsState(
                    targetValue = when(dismissState.targetValue){
                        Default -> Color.LightGray
                        DismissedToEnd -> Color.Green
                        DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                    }
                )
                val icon = when(direction){
                    StartToEnd -> Icons.Default.Done
                    EndToStart -> Icons.Default.Delete
                }
                val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                    if (dismissState.targetValue == Default) 0.8f else 1.2f
                )
                val alignment = when (direction) {
                    StartToEnd -> Alignment.CenterStart
                    EndToStart -> Alignment.CenterEnd
                }
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(color)
                    .padding(start = 12.dp, end = 12.dp),
                    contentAlignment = alignment
                ){
                    Icon(icon, contentDescription = "Icon", modifier = Modifier.scale(scale))
                }
            },
            dismissContent = {ItemScreen(dismissState = dismissState, item = item)}
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wait `currentValue` to become non `Default` and reset the state:

According to [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model), composable function should be free of side effects - you shouldn't directly reset the state in the composable scope. For such situations you need to use one of special side effect functions, more info can be found in side-effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Recomposition can happen many times, up to once a frame during animation, and not using side effect functions will lead to multiple calls, which can cause animation problems.

As `DismissState.reset()` is a `suspend` function, `LaunchedEffect` fits perfectly here: it's already running on a coroutine scope.

```
if (dismissState.currentValue != DismissValue.Default) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        dismissState.reset()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain, why LaunchedEffect(Unit) is used.

Comment: @Rahul check out updated answer.

Comment: I don't think this really solves the problem. The issue is that confirmStateChange is inside the definition of the dismiss state so I cannot reference it.

Comment: @IdhanosiYerimah `confirmStateChange` is called when user removes the finger from the screen, then, if you return `true`, it'll animate `dismissContent` to end dismiss animation. That's why here in my answer I wait `dismissState.currentValue` to become `DismissedToStart` before calling reset. But if you don't need to finish dismiss animation, you can return `false` and it'll animate to the original state. Note that from user perspective it may look like it haven't worked out.

Comment: Yes. In my case there was a confirmation dialog so i needed to reset the swipe state incase the user cancelled the operation. Changing the return boolean from true to false fixed it. Thanks @PhilDukhov